# Динамическое обновление данных на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, веб-программирование, arduino

У меня есть ethernet модуль для ардуино, на который я посылаю запрос - получаю ответ, всё понятно. Теперь я хочу чтобы у меня изменения данных отображались без обновления страницы (F5). Естественно хочется сделать минимальную нагрузку на сервер. Вот так выглядит страница:

```
void printWeb(int openCount, int light, float temperature, float moisture)
{
  BufferFiller bf = ether.tcpOffset();
  bf.emit_p(PSTR(
              "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n"
              "<html lang=\"ru\">"
              "<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">"
              "<body>"
              "<font size=\"6\">"
              "Вскрытий корпуса: $D<br>"
              "Уровень запылённости: $D %<br>"
              "Температура: $D &#x2103<br>"
              "Влажность: $D %<br>"
              "</font>"
              "</body>"
              "</html>"), openCount, 100 - (light - 26) / 10, static_cast<int>(temperature), static_cast<int>(moisture));

  ether.httpServerReply(bf.position());
}
```

Как я понимаю, после первой загрузки следует отправлять не всю страницу заново, а только сами значения показателей, но как это сделать?
А работает сейчас это так, что если пришли какие - либо пакеты, тогда мы посылаем ответ:

```
if (ether.packetLoop(ether.packetReceive()))
        {
          delay(10);
          printWeb(shockCounter, lt, tp, vl);
        }
```

Сделал вот так, но здесь отсылается вся страница и при этом у меня ардуино перезагружалась (вызов setup происходил постоянно), поэтому я не уверен в правильности, хотя оно и работало:

```
              "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n"

              "<html lang=\"ru\">"
              "<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">"
              "<body>"


              "<div id=\"response\">"
              "<font size=\"6\">"
              "Вскрытий корпуса: $D<br>"
              "Уровень запылённости: $D %<br>"
              "Температура: $D &#x2103<br>"
              "Влажность: $D %<br>"
              "</font>"

              "<script>"
              "setInterval(function(){"
              "var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();"
              "var typeMethod = \"GET\";"
              "xhr.open(typeMethod, \"http://192.168.1.200\");"
              "xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {"
              "if (this.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4) {"
              " document.getElementById(\"response\").innerHTML = this.responseText; } }"
              "\nxhr.send();"
              "}, 2000);"
              "</script>"
              "</div>"


              "</body>"
              "</html>"
```

Comment: Из глупых вариантов могу предложить заменить строчку с присвоением innerHTML на alert(this.responseText).

Если я правильно понял, то перезагружается после изменения ответа, возможно если закомментировать какие-то строки, то это поможет обнаружить причину ошибки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно выполнить `ajax` запрос на сервер. Понять на сервере, что пришел `ajax` запрос можно несколькими путями: 
1) с помощью параметра в запросе;
2) с помощью информации в заголовках (`HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH`);

Когда сервер понимает, что пришел `ajax` запрос, то он должен отдавать только нужные данные.

Вот простой пример на стороне сервера:

```
#include <EtherCard.h>

byte Ethernet::buffer[500];
BufferFiller bfill;

void setup () {
    ether.begin(sizeof Ethernet::buffer, { 0x74, 0x69, 0x69, 0x2D, 0x30, 0x31 }, 10);
    ether.staticSetup({ 192, 168, 1, 100 });
}

void loop () {
    // по идее получаем размер пакета
    word len = ether.packetReceive();
    word pos = ether.packetLoop(len);

    if (pos){
        // эмпирическим путем выясняем размер пакета
        Serial.prinln(len);

        BufferFiller bf = ether.tcpOffset();

        // больше 5 байт, соответствует запросу GET /....
        if(len > 5) {
            bf.emit_p(PSTR(
                "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n"
                "$D\n"
                "$D\n"
                "$D\n"
                "$D"), openCount, 100 - (light - 26) / 10, static_cast<int>(temperature), static_cast<int>(moisture));
        }
        else {
            bf.emit_p(PSTR(
                "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n"
                "<html lang=\"ru\">"
                "<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">"
                "<body>"
                "<font size=\"6\">"
                "Вскрытий корпуса: $D<br>"
                "Уровень запылённости: $D %<br>"
                "Температура: $D &#x2103<br>"
                "Влажность: $D %<br>"
                "</font>"
                "</body>"
                "</html>"), openCount, 100 - (light - 26) / 10, static_cast<int>(temperature), static_cast<int>(moisture));
        }

        ether.httpServerReply(bf.position());
    }
}
```

Что происходит? Мы получаем запрос, получаем размер запроса `ether.packetReceive()`, если он больше, чем размер `GET /` (Т.е. 5 байт, по байту на каждый символ), то логично, что в запросе есть еще какие-то параметры. Тем самым мы понимаем, что нам нужно отдать только значения.

Но как делать запросы без перезагрузки? В самом начале я говорил про ajax, давайте разберемся. Изменим HTML:

```
    "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n"
    "<html lang=\"ru\">"
    "<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">"
    "<body>"
    "<font size=\"6\">"
    "Вскрытий корпуса: <span id='korp'>$D</span><br>"
    "Уровень запылённости: <span id='dust'>$D</span> %<br>"
    "Температура: <span id='temp'>$D</span> &#x2103<br>"
    "Влажность: <span id='hum'>$D</span> %<br>"
    "</font>"
    "<script>function check() {" +
    " setTimeout(function() {" +
    "  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();" +
    "  xhr.open('GET', 'ajax', false); // false - синхронный запрос" +
    "  xhr.send();" +
    "  if (xhr.status == 200) {\n" +
    "    var values = xhr.responseText.split('\\n');" +
    "    document.getElementById('korp').innerHTML = values[0];" +
    "    document.getElementById('dust').innerHTML = values[1];" +
    "    document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = values[2];" +
    "    document.getElementById('hum').innerHTML = values[3];" +
    "   }" +
    "  check();" +
    " }, 1000);" +
    "}" +
    "check();</script>";
    "</body>"
```

Что изменилось? Добавили скрипт, который каждую секунду делает запрос на сервер, получает данные и изменяет их в `<span>`.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, но всё равно не работает. Как я понимаю, HTML со скриптом должен быть в else блоке, вот только я туда не попадаю, потому что размер пакетов получаемых равен не 5, а 498. Ну да ладно, заменил 5 на 498, условие срабатывает правильно, но вот только html со скриптом не работает. Если убрать весь блок script, то сайт отображается, а если скрипт оставить, то "Не удается получить доступ к сайту"

Comment: И ещё, разве в open методе надо не 'http://192.168.1.200/ajax' написать? В любом случае не работает, но просто уточняю

Comment: @МишаковМаксим тут в чем проблема: у меня негде такое тестить и я писал по наитию. Предлагаю вам открыть дебаггер в браузере и глянуть, почему не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Задача: получить веб-страничку с динамически обновляемыми данными.

Чего не хватает в решении автора:

Механизма для обращения к серверу после загрузки страницы. Для этого надо использовать на веб-странице дополнительный javascript. А точнее Ajax, или точнее XmlHttpRequest. А результат этого запроса должен специальной самописной функцией изменять страницу для подстановки актуальных данных.

Что было бы неплохо иметь для сокращения объемов траффика:

Нужно использовать функцию setInterval. В которой вы зададите интервал через который вы хотите вызывать получение данных. Иначе вы можете получить бесконечные запросы на сервер. Что разумеется излишняя нагрузка на сервер.

Если использовать подход одного ответа на любой http запрос. То на любой запрос отсылается полная страница. Тогда как если разнести страницу и сервис с данными на два адреса (/index.html и /data) то можно будет сократить траффик.

Comment: Я уже делал через XmlHttpRequest, оно работало, но не так хорошо как мне хотелось бы. Добавлю сейчас

Comment: Добавил детали про setInterval для контроля частоты запросов на сервер.